# Authing into Google with REST

Tags: rest, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to OAuth2 into Google Drive, but I'm having two problems:

1) Opening `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` kind of works. It does prompt the user to login, then redirects to the redirect uri.

The first time I did this the redirect url was appended with a query string with the access_token, etc. But every request since that first one has given me nothing, no access_token, no query string of any kind. What gives?

And 2) , I'm trying to get a list of files from `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files`. I'm giving it a query string with the oauth2 access_token but I keep getting the error:

```
domain: "global"  
location: "Authorization"  
locationType: "header"  
message: "Invalid Credentials"  
reason: "authError"
```

It seems I'm struggling with the basics here. Anyone know of a beginner google api tutorials that might help me?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the API? Have you tried using one of Google's API Client Libraries?

Comment: I'm trying to do this with straight get requests using the es6 fetch function. I'm in React Native, so the browser JavaScript library, I assume, won't work out of the box. And I'm trying to stay with a JavaScript only approach so I don't have to deal with native plugins.